# Table status in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I would love to add a table status to my laravel table.. I want a situation where by when a table is being created,its going to have a table status ""new then  after two day it's going to have a status "old"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need a new table/column for this in Laravel if you're using `timestamps`. You can check the `created_at` timestamp and compare against today; if `diffInDays()` is greater than 2, return "old" else return "new". For example, in your `model`:

`Example.php`:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Example extends Model {
  public function getStatusAttribute(){
    if(Carbon::now()->diffInDays($this->created_at) > 2){
      return "old";
    }
    return "new";
  }
}
```

Then, you can query your model and check the `status` attribute:

```
$example = Example::first();
dd($example->status); // Will be `"old"` or `"new"`
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what u mean by query my model And check the status attribute..can u explain better.. Thanks in advance 

Comment: The code is there. Is there something unclear about fetching a record from the Database and accessing one of it's properties?

Comment: Yes m a bit confused..I understood the first code you wrote should be written in my model but would the last code also be written in my model..sorry for the disturbance ☺

Comment: No, the code for querying would be done in a `Controller`, and accessing the attribute `->status` would be done anywhere you need it; either in some additional controller logic or in a view (such as displaying). Basically, you didn't say what you wanted to do with this column, so I provided an example, but you can use it anywhere as required.

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback.. Thank you so much..i appreciate.. Hope you see this

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a new column for this. You can use the `created_by` to calculate whether it's new/old. An [accessor function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) on the model makes it even easier:

```
public function getStatusAttribute() {
    return $this->created_at->gt(now()->subDays(2)) ? 'new' : 'old';
}
```

You can then access that value as `$model->status`.